# get values from two tables in one single view by stored procedure in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My model is

```
public partial class Device
{
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Device_Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Device_Name { get; set; }
}

public partial  class Customer
{
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_id { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display the values in both tables in one view i am using stored procedure to get the values..

I have written procedure to get the details from the 2 tables..I need the view to be like this.

```
<table >
  <tr>           
    <th>Device </th>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@Html.LabelForModel(item.Device_ModelNo)</td>
      <td>@Html.LabelForModel(item.Customer_Name)</td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Comment: So what's the problem here?

Comment: And it should be `DisplayFor()` not `LabelForModel()`

Comment: thanks , i   want the model class that accept  values from both classes Device and Customer

Comment: @Stephen LabelForModel() works for me when I print the values from tables separately

Comment: @sarath, `LabelFor()` generates a `<label>` element which is an accessibility element associated with a form control (clicking on it sets focus to the control). Using a `<label>` element is not appropriate here  - not to mention which it outputs the name of the property, not the value of the property :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Master class and include this two classes like this

```
public class Master
{
  public Device  device { get; set; }
  public Customer customer { get; set; }
}
```

Now type your view with the master class

```
@model MasterModel
```

Comment: I think you mean `@model IEnumerable<Master>` :)

Comment: @Stephen  @Html.DisplayForModel(item.Device_ModelNo) is not working in this way...